# Private and Public variables in a method Java

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

Say I have a class that uses multiple ArrayLists:

```
public static ArrayList<String> openable = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> mail = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> mailCommands = new ArrayList<>();
public static ArrayList<String> previousCommands = new ArrayList<>();
```

And I have multiple other classes that contain methods that use those ArrayLists. Say I also have a class called connect, that extends this first class containing those variable:

```
public class Connect extends Main_Menu{
```

If I were to call the methods that I usually call in the `Main_Menu` class, from the Connect class using new variables with the same name that are private:

```
private static ArrayList<String> previousCommands = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<String> openable = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> mail = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<String> mailCommands = new ArrayList<>();
```

Would the method using these ArrayLists use the data from the public variables in the `Main_Menu` class or would it use the private data from the variables in the `Connect` class?

Comment: `private` fields don't become `public`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I never said they did? Im asking if there are two variables with the same name, one that is public and one that isn't, and it is called from a method that uses one of the variables, which one does it use?

Comment: They're variables in two different classes; of course they're different. Running a rudimentary test case would show this immediately without having to wonder. Unrelated, but please stick with Java naming conventions, e.g., `MainMenu`.

Comment: It's not 100% clear what you're asking, but it appears to fundamentally be about [**name masking**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_(programming_languages)#Name_masking).

Comment: I just have a few suggestions. You can ignore them but I hope you try to at least consider. First don't ever make non-final variables public--absolute rule, shouldn't be allowed in the language, and even if those were final, it's best not to make mutable objects public. This is so widely accepted that even if you knew what you were doing and violated one of these rules intentionally you'd have to defend your code to almost anyone who saw it.  Second--You'll find yourself much happier if you avoid the statics.  Create a single instance with non-static members instead of a class full of statics.

Answer (score 1):

see for yourself:

```
static class Parent
{ 
    public static int A = 5;

    public static int B = 18;

    public static int getA(){
        return A;
    }

    public static int getB(){
        return B;
    }
}

static class Child extends Parent
{
    private static int A = 10;

    public static int getA(){
        return A;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent p = new Parent();
    Child c = new Child();
    System.out.println("Parent A: " + p.getA());
    System.out.println("Parent B: " + p.getB());
    System.out.println("Child A: " + c.getA());
}
```

output:

```
run:
Parent A: 5
Parent B: 18
Child A: 10
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: The OP did specifically mention that the fields were static. Your code is a great representation of method and field overriding, but not of a child class overriding a static field with a narrowed scope.

Comment: @JordanGrant it makes no difference, the scope rules are the same.

Comment: They are not. You provided public methods to access private fields, so of course your example worked. When I point out the shortcoming of your shortcut, you ninja edited your code into something that does not compile. You cannot have static fields within a static class. You have attempted to shortcut an example for OP, but have circumvented the OPs real question.

Comment: @JordanGrant you are correct I did update my answer to be more concise, however I ran it on my machine again to make sure that it was correct. If you cant copy paste that is your problem. Also you should read Java's documentation before you make comments like "You cannot have static fields within a static class" because, as it turns out, you can.

Comment: I can cut and paste; the code as shown here has a `main` method outside of any class; I think you forgot to wrap it up in your test class since there aren't top-level static classes either. Just sayin'. Before tossing attitude around it's usually good to do a sanity check, just in case :) I'd also say this doesn't really show the issue asked by the OP.

Comment: @DaveNewton you are correct that I did not grab my test class as the OP did not provide me with one so I thought it would add confusion (I can add it back if you think it would help). Furthermore I do not see how this misses what the OP was asking. From what I understand he is trying to figure out which version of a static field will be used. This example shows that with the methods `getA` and `getB`. Is that not what the OP wanted to test?

Answer (score -1):

I suppose that the static fields in the Connect class are merely overriding the visibility of the same fields in the Main_Menu class. Outside of the scope of the Connect class, the field is not visible, and so you can't access it. You would get an exception if you could even compile at all.

Edit: I am assuming that you are accessing these static variables directly, and not accessing private fields through overridden methods as suggested by other users.

Main.java:

```
public class Main {
    public static ArrayList<String> things = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Playground.things;  // <- Cannot access private static field outside of that class
    }
}
```

Playground.java:

```
public class Playground extends Main {
        private static ArrayList<String> things = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```